# A batch file to check internet connection and shutdown pc, if offline

Tags: batch-file, shutdown

The title pretty much says it all. So, I have a no-break connected to my PC, because we have a lot of blackouts here where I live. The problem is: if I'm not at home, who will shutdown my PC correctly if there is a blackout? So, I realized that my modem is not connected to the no-break; this means that, in the case of a black-out, my modem will turn off, thus, no internet will reach my computer, so this is kind of a way to tell my PC when lights are out. 
Sure, this might not be always the case (sometimes the internet just goes off for reasons other than power), but I will accept this risk.
So, what I am looking for is a code that, once I execute it (what I'll do when I'm leaving home), checks if there is internet conection. If yes, than do nothing and keep checking. If not, than shutdown the computer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you should show a piece of code of what do you have tested. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Indeed. Please try to write something on your own at first. This is not a free scripting site. You could check for parsing commands in batch and try to find a command for checking the connection status in batch, mix'em up and go with that. You can take your network cable out for example to test your file.